# fail to pass reactive value to variables in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to dynamically chop the image in shiny with `imager::imsub`. The result is empty image, according to the values printed, I realize that the values inputed fails to pass to the variable `subArea` as expected.

More worse, even the values defined in `reactiveVlaues` didn't show up. Doesn't the `reactiveValues` be regarded as initial values which will change when the environment and dependants changed?

Please find the toy sample for your reference.

Besides the `empty image` msg, I also get error msg `(subscript) logical subscript too long` which only show up when I make the `imsub` part uncommented, have no clue where the error comes from. Many thanks.

[image: Rlogo]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(imager)
{
rm(list=ls())

ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = NULL),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sliderInput("ixs", "init x start", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
      sliderInput("ixr", "init x range", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
      sliderInput("iys", "init y start", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
      sliderInput("iyr", "init y range", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
      actionButton("submit", "submit")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      plotOutput("pl"),
      textOutput("txt")
    )
  )

server <- 
  function(input, output, session) {

    #subArea <- list()
    im <- load.image("Rlogo.png")

    subArea <- reactiveValues(xs = 0, xr = 500, ys = 0, yr =500)

    observeEvent(input$submit,{
      subArea$xs <- input$ixs
      subArea$ys <- input$iys
      subArea$xr <- input$ixr
      subArea$yr <- input$iyr
    })
      subArea$xs <- 0
      subArea$ys <- 0
      subArea$xr <- dim(im)[1]
      subArea$yr <- dim(im)[2]

    output$txt <- 
      renderPrint(cat(c(
        paste0("   submit", input$submit  ),
        paste0("   dim =", dim(im)[1:2]  ),
        paste0("   ixs =", input$ixs),
        paste0("   ixr =", input$ixr),
        paste0("   iys =", input$iys),
        paste0("   iyr =", input$iyr),
        paste0("subArea$ixs =", subArea$ixs),
        paste0("subArea$ixr =", subArea$ixr),
        paste0("subArea$iys =", subArea$iys),
        paste0("subArea$iyr =", subArea$iyr)
        ))) 

    output$pl <- renderPlot({

      load.image("Rlogo.png") %>% 
        imsub( x > subArea$xs,
               x < subArea$rx,
               y > subArea$ys,
               y < subArea$yr) %>%
        plot
    })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to typos.  See the below.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(imager)
{
  rm(list=ls())

  ui <- 
    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = NULL),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sliderInput("ixs", "init x start", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
        sliderInput("ixr", "init x range", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
        sliderInput("iys", "init y start", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
        sliderInput("iyr", "init y range", value = 50, min = 1, max = 250),
        actionButton("submit", "submit")
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        plotOutput("pl"),
        textOutput("txt")
      )
    )

  server <- 
    function(input, output, session) {

      #subArea <- list()
      im <- load.image("Rlogo.png")

      subArea <- reactiveValues(xs = 0, xr = 500, ys = 0, yr =500)

      observeEvent(input$submit,{
        subArea$xs <- input$ixs
        subArea$ys <- input$iys
        subArea$xr <- input$ixr
        subArea$yr <- input$iyr
      })
      subArea$xs <- 0
      subArea$ys <- 0
      subArea$xr <- dim(im)[1]
      subArea$yr <- dim(im)[2]

      output$txt <- 
        renderPrint(cat(c(
          paste0("   submit", input$submit  ),
          paste0("   dim =", dim(im)[1:2]  ),
          paste0("   ixs =", input$ixs),
          paste0("   ixr =", input$ixr),
          paste0("   iys =", input$iys),
          paste0("   iyr =", input$iyr),
          #paste0("subArea$ixs =", subArea$ixs),
          #paste0("subArea$ixr =", subArea$ixr),
          #paste0("subArea$iys =", subArea$iys),
          #paste0("subArea$iyr =", subArea$iyr)
          paste0("subArea$ixs =", subArea$xs),
          paste0("subArea$ixr =", subArea$xr),
          paste0("subArea$iys =", subArea$ys),
          paste0("subArea$iyr =", subArea$yr)
      ))) 

      output$pl <- renderPlot({

        load.image("Rlogo.png") %>% 
          imsub( x > subArea$xs,
                 #x < subArea$rx,
                 x < subArea$xr,
                 y > subArea$ys,
                 y < subArea$yr) %>%
          plot
      })

    }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Kota Mori san. aligado gozaimasu